# How to freeze a Solana nfts with React?

Tags: solana, nft

I did a lot of research on this subject but could not reach a conclusion.
What I want to do is this;
I list and display the NFTs in my user's wallet using a specific collectionKey (my own collectionKey). From here, the user will select an NFT and perform the freezing process. This may or may not be for a certain period of time. The user will select and confirm the freezing process and I will give him a special reward (like points) from my system. How do I do this? How can I find a library/framework code sample or how to do it for React?

Some documents that I have examined and tried the codes of:
https://spl.solana.com/token#freezing-accounts
https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/lock
https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/available-guards/freeze-token-payment